# How to add tooltip in Magento 2

Tags: user-interface, magento, magento2

I am using a custom template and just added:

```
<span class="custom-tooltip">
    <a href="#" class="tooltip-toggle">Test ?</a>
    <span class="tooltip-content">Tolltip description come here</span>
</span>
```

and than added below style code in my theme `styles-l.css`

```
.custom-tooltip {
    .lib-tooltip(right);
}
```

but its not working, am I doing wrong or missing.

Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

Add following code is in less file

```
.custom-tooltip {
    .lib-tooltip(right);
}
```

and run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` command

checked in magento version 2.1.7 to magneto version 2.2.2

Comment: In which less file need to add this CSS?

Comment: @senthil page.less

Comment: thanks, now it's working, but for the mobile device, it's not working. so for that what i need to add

Answer (score 0):

The code below can be just added to .phtml template:

```
        <div class="field-tooltip toggle">
            <span class="field-tooltip-action action-help"
                  data-bind="mageInit: {'dropdown':{'activeClass': '_active'}}" data-toggle="dropdown"
                  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></span>
                <div class="field-tooltip-content" data-target="dropdown" aria-hidden="true">
                    It is default Magento tooltip. Already styled.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).